# How to consume WCF method with "DataSet" return type in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, wcf

10+ Methods in my WCF webservice returns an object of type DataSet

```
 public System.Data.DataSet ReturnData()
        {
            DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
            //do some work on the dataset
            return dataSet;
        }
```

I want to consume this WCF webservice in my silverlight application.

Problem: DataSet is not resolved as System.Data.dll does not appear in the Silverlight application's add reference section.

Is there a workaround or a solution?

Comment: The developer who wrote a WCF service with methods returning a DataSet should be punished. I would understand a legacy ASMX web service returning DataSets, but WCF? It's like buying a Ferrari and driving it only on routes with 20mph speed limit.

Comment: @Darin - +1 this is so true, I was thinking the very same thing.

Comment: @Darin: +1 more text to meet the minimum character count

Comment: Even legacy ASMX web services shouldn't have returned DataSets.  I remember reading some guidance in ... 2005? that really frowned upon that practice.

Comment: Solution is simple: just  **don't** use datasets (anymore) - use real objects, collections or lists thereof - use an ORM for your data access.

Comment: I kind of disagree because it all depends.  the problem is that these datasets contain data tables in them. these datatables contain huge data. instead of making multiple calls to the database, the wcf service returns a dataset which contained all of the data tables. the data in the data tables is used to populate charts. Changing the return type to another type will over kill the amount of coding on the silverlight side.  if you can recommend how classes and lists/observable collections could be used in this scenario then that would be really great.

Comment: @fm55: again - you should **not** be returning *huge data* to a Silverlight app - return just as much as is needed on a single screen - not more. Otherwise you'll **never** have decent performance.... this is **not** a classic desktop app with a local dBase file; it's a distributed system. Don't transfer **huge** data! Just **DON'T** !

Comment: @Marc_s, Out of curosity, as silverlight is a client's app, does it mean that the data set with multiple data tabels data will live(not sure if that's the right word) inside client's browser while the browser is displaying silverlight app?  Also, do you recommend that I rather make multiple calls to the WCF service and return lists eachtime?

Comment: @fm55, use POCO objects instead of DataSet. A DataSet already uses XML serialization and WCF also so you're gonna do a double, triple, quadruple XML serialization which is horrible.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to create some classes now. Scenario is (im trying to simply it but it will make sense) I will show a list of persons in a grid. When a person row is clicked, I will show all of its details e.g. number of cats. if I then select number of cats, it will show me the cat names. clicking on a cat will bring up its details. If I use POCO objects with collections e.g. List<Persons> then if I select a person, do you recommend that I make a service call to get the details and then display it or should I bring all of the details (including related entity's details) in one go? Thanks.

Comment: if i bring data in one go then again the data will be huge.  my aim is to have silverlight app with good performance. if i retrieve data as required then the WCF service will be opening database connections for each user click to retrieve data.  This will slow the application down...

Comment: @fm55: you should investigate server-side paging: e.g. have the server return e.g. 20 or 50 people at once, including their cats and dogs and all :-) - that should remain manageable. If you need to - go fetch another 20 or 50 of them. Do client-side caching of those you've already retrieved so you can page back into earlier data as quickly as possible.

Comment: Thanks Marc_S.  A lot of code will change now but I've learnt from my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look on DataSet for [Silverlight Applications](http://silverlightdataset.net/silverlightdataset/Default.aspx)

But I advise you to write this into classes

**Edit:**
To show you how you can use instead of the classe, I give you an example

```
  public class Person
    {
        private int gID;
        private String gFirstName="";
        private String gLastName = "";


        public int ID
        {
            get 
            {
                return gID;
            }
            set
            {
                gID = value;
            }
        }

        public String FirstName
        {
            get
            {
                return gFirstName;
            }
            set
            {
                gFirstName= value;
            }
        }


        public String LastName
        {
            get
            {
                return gLastName;
            }
            set
            {
                gLastName = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

.

```
   public class Persons
    {
        private List<Person> gListOfPerson;

        public List<Person> All
        {
            get
            {
                if (gListOfPerson == null)
                {
                    gListOfPerson= new List<Person>();
                }
                return gListOfPerson;
            }
            set
            {
                gListOfPerson=value;
            }
        }

    }
```

.

```
public Persons ReturnData()
{            
                 DataSet  vDS = new DataSet();
                 //get data from SQL Server or what ever in a DataSet...

                foreach(System.Data.DataTable t in vDS.Tables)
                {
                    Persons  vPersons = new Persons();
                    foreach(System.Data.DataRow dr in t.Rows)
                    {
                        Person vPerson = new Person();
                        int vtryInt;
                        int.TryParse(dr["ID"].ToString(), out vtryInt);
                        vPerson.ID = vtryInt;
                        vPerson.FirstName = dr["FirstName"].toString();
                        vPerson.LastName = dr["LastName"].toString();

                        vPersons.All.Add(vPerson);
                    }


                    return vPersons ;
 }
```

Comment: Thank you.  I will hopefully create a generic wrapper class to convert a data set to list<T>. As it was mentioned in one of the comments above that I should not retrieve all of the data in one go, do you also recommend retrieving data as and when needed. Person class above has a property of another class, call it List<Cat>.  Cat class itself has another property of List<Owners>.  All of this information will be retrieved from the database. Do you recommend that I bring Persons first and then Cats if and when required or to bring everything in one go.

Comment: Yes, you can create the tree of classes as high as you want!
But I would say that you get only the data you **need**! The data that you do not get displayed to a user can be retrieved during later! A user does not want to wait several years for things to arrive;). But of course there are exceptions

Comment: A good rule is that as **LOT** of logic as possible should be on the server, and not with the client.
Please mark the answer as answered, if it gave you the answer you want:)

Comment: You certainly did.  Thank you.  Btw, as silverlight is a client's app, does it mean that the tree if classes will live inside client's browser while the browser is displaying silverlight app? or will they be in the server?

Comment: The definition of the class will be at the client as well, to give a silverlight overview on how it will read the WCF send and how to send back. When you get a little more hang of this, I recommend you also to Dispose() all the objects you know you will not use again ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fs2xkftw(v=vs.71).aspx ). But this is another subject,so do not worry about it now!.

Comment: That I understand.  My question is different, may be I was unclear.  It was mentioned that silverlight is a client app. Does it mean that if I fetch a huge data and then perform some heavy processes on the data in my view model classes e.g. recursion, manipulation using Math functions etc,  will it consume memory from client's machine or web server?

Comment: Yes, until you take it away again! After the same object with the clientele need to see. Say you have a grid with 89999999 rows in from database, you will then upload all the client? NO of course not! Then if you take a number and then reload when the user scrolling down.